# How to load data to a ListFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-listfragment

I'm trying to load some data into a `ListFragment` but I'm getting this error:

```
05-07 00:05:30.533   625-625/com.myapp.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

How can I handle this?

Here are my files, if they can help:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewpagerAdapter viewpagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewpagerAdapter = new ViewpagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewpagerAdapter);

}

}
```

ListFrag.java

```
public class ListFrag extends ListFragment {

private DatabaseAdapter databaseAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listagem, container, false);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    databaseAdapter = new DatabaseAdapter(getActivity());
    databaseAdapter.open();

    List<Foo> values = databaseAdapter.getAllFoobar();

    //ArrayAdapter<Foo> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Foo>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    //setListAdapter(adapter);

}

}
```

And fragment.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myapp.android.ListFrag">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Crash log clearly says the issue . You need to change the `ListView` id . `ListFragment` expects the layout to have `ListView` id as `@android:id/list`

```
 android:id="@android:id/list"
```

If you look at the `ListFragment` source code , its checks for the `ListView` in the layout using `android.R.id.list` `ID`. If the view is null it will throw an `RuntimeException`

```
      View rawListView = root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        if (!(rawListView instanceof ListView)) {
            if (rawListView == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException(
                        "Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is " +
                        "'android.R.id.list'");
            }
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' "
                    + "that is not a ListView class");
        }
```

Use this Layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```